# How do I crop an image in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Let's say I have a rectangular, portrait image:

[image]

I'd like to crop it, such that it's rendered like this:

[image]

How can I do this in Flutter?

(I don't need to resize the image.)

(Image from https://flic.kr/p/nwXTDb)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I would probably use a [`BoxDecoration`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) with a [`DecorationImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/DecorationImage-class.html). You can use the `alignment` and `fit` properties to determine how your image is cropped. You can use an [`AspectRatio`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) widget if you don't want to hard code a height on the `Container`.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Image Crop Example"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 487 / 451,
          child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                image: new NetworkImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png'),
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wow i had different issue, but this BoxDecoration technique worked out for me. Thanks man :)

Comment: You are trying to crop the file while rendering it. However, I want to store the cropped version of the image and then render it. Do you know of any such technique or package?

Comment: Hi, I want to show part of the image in **both** directions. Say I have 1080x1920 image, and I want to show (x=100~200, y=300~400) part. Thus I cannot use this fit+alignment method. How can I do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

You can also directly use the [Image](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html) class with [BoxFit](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) and do something like:

```
new Image.asset(
  stringToImageLocation,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
)
```

Comment: Worked with `DecorationImage` as well

Comment: Hi, I want to show part of the image in both directions. Say I have 1080x1920 image, and I want to show (x=100~200, y=300~400) part. Thus I cannot use this fit+alignment method. How can I do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Provide a `fit` factor to your `Image` widget and then wrap it in `AspectRatio`.

```dart
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1.5, 
  child: Image.asset(
    'your_image_asset',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

Comment: By far the most helpful answer <3 Bravo!

Answer (score 15):

Take a look to [brendan-duncan/image](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image), it's platform-independent library to manipulate images in Dart.

You can use the function:

```
Image copyCrop(Image src, int x, int y, int w, int h);
```

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried it with Flutter? I'm wondering how to get a Flutter Image in and out of brendan's image library.

Comment: I don't think Flutter provides an easy way to get the decoded image out of a `ui.Image`. But if you use brendan's image library to do the decoding, you can call `image.getBytes()` and pass that to a `new Image.memory`

Comment: Is it possible to add example on how to do it in Flutter from network image? I'm trying to crop image at specific `{ x: 897, y: 235, width: 845, height: 845 }` values, but can't find anything that could work for me.

Answer (score 7):

**Worked for me using just these 2 properties:**

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,// OR BoxFit.fitWidth
  alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
  ....
)
```

Comment: This helped to me!

Answer (score 4):

There is a new package called `ImageCropper`. I would recommend everyone to use this instead as it has many features and makes everything easier. It allows you to crop the image to any or specified aspect ratio you want and can even compress the image. Here is the link to the package: https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper

Comment: how to add a custom ratio from this package?

Comment: can please answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66454096/how-to-add-custom-crop-ratio-into-image-cropper-library-flutter ?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in docs or SC, can you please help me with a code snippet?

Comment: I found this in ImageCropper's repo: https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper/issues/80

Comment: Thanks, @uni , Yes that's right, but it only helps to show only one aspect ratio in fact if we use aspectRatio it will lock all the list from the aspectRatioPresets.

Comment: I need to Use 2 custom ratios, but aspectRatio only accepts one.

Comment: Based from https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper/issues/81, ios doesn't support multiple custom ratios during 2019. I'm not sure if it still remains the same this 2021. You'd have to ask the maintainer if this is now supported.

Answer (score 4):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  /// Variables
  File imageFile;

  /// Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0XFF307777),
          title: Text("Image Cropper"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: imageFile == null
                ? Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RaisedButton(
                          color: Color(0XFF307777),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _getFromGallery();
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "PICK FROM GALLERY",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    child: Image.file(
                      imageFile,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  )));
  }

  /// Get from gallery
  _getFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    _cropImage(pickedFile.path);
  }

  /// Crop Image
  _cropImage(filePath) async {
    File croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: filePath,
      maxWidth: 1080,
      maxHeight: 1080,
    );
    if (croppedImage != null) {
      imageFile = croppedImage;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I crop file to square.
I use [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) library.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class CropperService {
  static const _side = 1800;

  Future<File> cropImageFile(File file, [int? side]) async {
    final image = await img.decodeImageFile(file.path);
    if (image == null) throw Exception('Unable to decode image');
    final croppedImage = img.copyResizeCropSquare(image, size: _side);
    final croppedFile = await _convertImageToFile(croppedImage, file.path);
    return croppedFile;
  }

  Future<File> _convertImageToFile(img.Image image, String path) async {
    final newPath = await _croppedFilePath(path);
    final jpegBytes = img.encodeJpg(image);

    final convertedFile = await File(newPath).writeAsBytes(jpegBytes);
    await File(path).delete();
    return convertedFile;
  }

  Future<String> _croppedFilePath(String path) async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    return join(
      tempDir.path,
      '${basenameWithoutExtension(path)}_compressed.jpg',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code got me started in the right direction! Curious if there is a way to avoid temp files?

Comment: I guest you can use getApplicationDocumentsDirectory or getApplicationSupportDirectory depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Selected image from gallery and we can crop it using image_cropper dependency in flutter.

```
 Dependency :   image_cropper: ^1.4.1
```

Code when we select image from gallery:

```
Future<void> pickFromGallery() async {
try {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  if (pickedImage == null) return;

  final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
    sourcePath: pickedImage.path,
    aspectRatioPresets: [
      CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
    ],
    androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
      toolbarTitle: 'Crop Image',
      toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      lockAspectRatio: false,
    ),
    iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
      title: 'Crop Image',
      aspectRatioLockEnabled: false,
    ),
  );

  if (croppedImage == null) return;

  final croppedFile = File(croppedImage.path);

  setState(() {
    this.image = croppedFile;
  });

  print("Image path: ${croppedFile.path}");
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print("Failed to pick or crop image: $e");
}
```

}

and please sure to add activity to AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

The output be like :

[image: Crop feature be like]

You can crop your image in various size.