# Image crop and rotate

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm currently building an Android app natively that has the functionality to take a photo and edit it right away (crop and rotate). Recently I heard of flutter and I'm interested in it, and I wonder if there's any way to do the same thing with what I've done natively using [this library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a similar question with answers already

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i've been searching and found no answers

Comment: Have you looked at: https://flutter.io/platform-channels/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665720/how-do-i-crop-an-image-in-flutter/44665742#44665742

Comment: @MorrisonChang ah i didn't knew about that yet, thanks!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i've seen that one, and it's different from my case, thanks btw

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Zoe Well first I'm sorry if my question is off-topic, it's my first question I asked on Stack Overflow and I didn't know about that, and actually I'm not just asking for library, I asked if there's any way to do that with flutter

Comment: @SeptianDwiIndradi then you need to rephrase your question: `Recently I heard of flutter and I'm interested in it, and I wonder if there's any **packages or something that can do the same thing with what I've done natively using this library**`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I crop an image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665720/how-do-i-crop-an-image-in-flutter)