# Flutter image crop and transform.

Tags: image, plugins, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there a plug-in that allows you to pick an image from the gallery or take an image with the camera and transform that image live ( the user can crop or scale the image using predefined aspect ratios ) in flutter for both iOS and Android?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665720/how-do-i-crop-an-image-in-flutter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I crop an image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665720/how-do-i-crop-an-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

The [image_cropper](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_cropper) plugin is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try flutter [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) to select the image and the built-in flutter [image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image) library to edit pictures