# How to add custom crop ratio into image_cropper library - Flutter

Tags: flutter, image-processing, flutter-layout, crop, flutter-dependencies

I know Image_cropper support predefined crop ratio like

```
 aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],
```

But I need to add a custom ratio say 9x16 or 7x5. What is the best solution for it?

https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper

Answer (score 3):

I have not be able to find a way to provide a list of "unique" aspect ratios using only one cropImage call, however you can provide a single aspect ratio in X, Y form.

you could have a UI button labeled "crop 9x16" and another button labeled "crop 7x5" with the following method inside the button's on_pressed function.

```
ImageCropper.cropImage(
  sourcePath: path, // your image file path
  aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 9, ratioY: 16)) //your desired aspect ratio
```